# boost test on windows with mingw compiler error: putenv not declared

Tags: windows, gcc, c++11, mingw, boost-test

I'm trying to compile a library on windows with mingw, that uses boost.
I compiled boost with:

```
 bootstrap mingw
 b2 toolset=gcc
```

After that I build the library with cmake and mingw.
Building the dll itself works fine, but when I try to build the tests, I get:

```
C:/boost/boost_1_55_0/boost/test/utils/runtime/config.hpp:95:51: error: 'putenv'
 was not declared in this scope
 putenv( const_cast<char*>( fs.str().c_str() ) );
```

So the error comes from a boost header and I have no idea how to fix that.

The repo of what I'm trying to build: https://github.com/linges/daestruct

It uses c99 and c++11.

Comment: Building a collection of C++ libraries with a C `std` flag certainly seems misguided...

Comment: Good point! That was an artifact from trying to build the library. I removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in boost. It has been happened to others, too:

https://github.com/BoostGSoC/boost.afio/commit/1b06855b6e20a01a3c4461c6d2d54e16eb3c8e21

The solution (or better: workaround) is to add the following lines before the inclusion of `boost::test`:

```
#ifdef __MINGW32__
// Mingw doesn't define putenv() needed by Boost.Test
extern int putenv(char*);
#endif
```